# How to implement small graphs to show distribution of spending in multiple categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

10 people submitted monthly spending patterns for four categories of spending, "gas, groceries, restaurants, and entertainment (ent)".

I would like to show a small grid of graphs summarizing the spending so you can see in each category the distribution of the spending.

Here are the issues with my code below.

1. The four separate graphs with the shared x-axis are good. However, I want the y-axis to reflect the amount of people at that level of spending, not four categories as it does now.
2. Looking at "grocery" for example, it appears there are some people with negative spending. I guess this is an artifact of using, `geom_density_ridges`. What would be a better choice?

```
library("tidyverse")
library("ggridges")

spend_df <- tibble(
  gas = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100),
  grocery = c(200, 200, 200, 500, 500, 500, 1200, 1200, 1200, 2200),
  ent = c(0, 0, 50, 50, 50, 50, 1000, 1100, 1200, 3000),
  restaurant = c(500, 0, 50, 2000, 20, 120, 220, 5, 250, 1000)
)

# Make long
spend_long <- spend_df |> 
  gather(category, category_monthly_spend, gas:restaurant) 

# Reorder ridgelines
spend_long$category <- factor(spend_long$category,
                              levels = c("gas", "grocery", "restaurant", "ent"))

ggplot(spend_long, aes(x = category_monthly_spend, y = category)) + 
  geom_density_ridges() + facet_wrap(~category)
```

Comment: Density is a poor choice here as you have too few data points to approximate the distribution with any accuracy. I would also not use facets - there is no point faceting on a variable which is also on one of the axes. I'd plot category (x) versus spend (y) and use `geom_jitter`.

Comment: The actual data will be considerably greater. Is there an easy way to make a grid of four category (x) versus spend (y) plots or are they each done individually?

Comment: There are lots of ways to make grids that don't involve facets: try searching for cowplot, patchwork or ggarrange packages. Facets could work, just not with the same variable on an axis. You could try just `geom_density` instead of ridges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your real data has more than 10 observations, and that you do want a density-like visualization of distribution, perhaps just `geom_density` with facets could work?

You may also want to experiment with `scales = "free_y"` in the facets.

```
spend_long %>% 
  ggplot(aes(category_monthly_spend)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_wrap(~category)
```

Result:

[image]